# Dynamically reboot server periodically using cronjob

Tags: server, cron, reboot

What command should I add in cron, so that it reboot the server after seven days of up time at specific time.

I can use `@daily root /sbin/shutdown -r now` to do that daily at assigned time, but I was not able to figure out the modification for seven days.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dow, or Day of Week, part of the crontab syntax, to execute the command on every occurrence of a particular day, using numbers in the form:

> 0-6 Sunday to Saturday
>
> 1-7 Monday to Sunday

Or even shortened word notation such as `WED` or `THU` for Wednesday or Thursday

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
00 07 * * 5 your-command-here
```

The example above would run the command at 7:00 am every Friday